# ?? and || Operator timing

Tags: c#, timing, null-coalescing-operator

I am starting to learn C# and have just started using the `??` operator, but am slightly confused about the timing. Take the below code example:

```
    string x = null;
    string y = null;
    string v = null;

    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x ?? y ?? v ?? y ?? v))
    {

    }

    watch.Stop();
    var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedTicks;
    Console.WriteLine(elapsedMs.ToString());

    watch.Restart();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(y) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(v) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(y) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(v))
    {

    }

    var elapsedMs2 = watch.ElapsedTicks;
    Console.WriteLine(elapsedMs2.ToString());
```

The result i get is that the first if statement takes around 100 ticks whilst the second usually around 3. I was under the impression that both of these would be similar in timing, or that the second if statement with the `||` would take longer.

Obviously i am missing something here. I thought that after the first `x` was evaluated to null that would be it and the rest wouldn't be evaluated. Is anyone able to explain what i am getting wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you maybe have the definition of `??` backward? `a ?? b` means:

- If `a` is null, `b`
- Otherwise, `a`

So if the left side is **not** null, then we don't evaluate `b`, since we know `a ?? b` is `a`. If `a` **is** null, as in your case, we *do* have to evaluate `b`.

`if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x ?? y ?? v ?? y ?? v))`

runs as:

- Evaluate `x`.
- That evaluates as null, so evaluate `y`.
- That evaluates as null, so evaluate `v`.
- That evaluates as null, so evaluate `y`.
- That evaluates as null, so evaluate `v`.
- That evaluates as null. Pass this value (null) into `string.IsNullOrEmpty`.
- That evaluates as `true`. Enter the block.

`if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(y) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(v) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(y) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(v))`

evaluates as:

- Evaluate `x`.
- That evaluates as null. Pass this value (null) into `string.IsNullOrEmpty`.
- That evaluates as `true`. Since `||` is satisfied if only one of the sides is true, we do not evaluate the right side of the first `||`, or any further to the right. Enter the block.

Comment: Ahh ok, thankyou! I should have maybe put more focus into learning what the operator actually does before jumping into testing the timings.